# How to host Jenkins on docker image which was previously using Jenkins server?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-docker

So I had my Jenkins running on EC2 Instance we backed up everything by creating a tar file of jenkins_home folder and saved it.
We had requirement tp run that Jenkins on docker image due to boot up Jenkins installation issues so what i did what ran

```
docker run -d --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:2.375
```

and copied the jar file in the docker container jenkins_home folder

```
docker cp /jenkins-jar/. pci-jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```

When I tried to connect to Jenkins I was getting
`jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds does not exist and probably cannot be created at jenkins.model.Jenkins.checkRawBuildsDir(Jenkins.java:3381) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3303) Caused: java.io.IOException at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3306) at jenkins.model.Jenkins$12.run(Jenkins.java:3401) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305) at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120) at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:290) at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1196) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:986) at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86) at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82) at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247) Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)`